# Later.js - text parse is o.k but interval didnt work

Tags: javascript, laterjs

**Situation**: in my code I am working with later js for interval by time with the text parser.
I parse 3 diffrent cases: hourly, daily, weekly
the parsing in all 3 cases is good! (return schduale.error = -1).

**problam:** daily and weekly didn't working for me if I am sets it to the close time
example: if the time now is 1:45 pm in tuesday
I defined:
daily: at "01:48 pm also at 01:50 pm"
weekly: "at 01:50 pm am on Tuesday and Wednsday "

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problam solved !
It was time zone that didnt sync between my time to later js.
all you need to do is to add the commend:

```
const later = require ('later'); //the reqiure you already have
later.date.localTime()
```

There is no any doc on this in later js.
but i found this in issues :https://github.com/bunkat/later/issues/95

good luck!